# Conditional price in readonly text field

Tags: entities

I have a content type to create membership for a plan, There are around 900 kind of price based on condition. I know conditional field only make visible the text-field when criteria match but if I create text field for each price then my content type will have more than 1000 fields and that is some kind of fussy isn't it ?

So can anybody suggest me any other option to do it, like I know first 4 condition, based on which the value has to come, I can make table for it...but how to go forward to make it appear in content creation page ?

Comment: what are the main conditions?

Comment: 1st Select - Plan Type(total 8), 2nd Select - Season Type(total 4), 3rd Select - Apartment Type(Total 2)...so for each combination different price is there...then for each price there are one full payment amount, down payment amount, balance amount if down payment selected...the whole lot of table consisting around 900 values..

Comment: As I have already lots of other fields like personnel details, nominee details, reference person details..around 160 fields...so keep making this fields and using conditional field...is really messy with content type..

Comment: is there any type or relationship. that is plan 1 means this a set amount and when you select the season type it would add that to the plan is it that way or there is no relation at all

Comment: There is relation like -- 1BR(apartment type) under PURPLE(seasons type) under SILVER STANDARD PLAN(plan type) has price 5,20,220 & STUDIO(apartment type) under PURPLE(seasons type) under SILVER STANDARD PLAN(plan type) has price 4,65,000...& so on...

Comment: What I mean to ask is is there any particular relation ship say for example if you select the PURPLE the price would be increased by 10% from the base price if you select 1BR the price would increase by another 20% etc is there any such relation?

Comment: No..there is no relation between them of this kind..though for each price FULL PAYMENT, DOWN PAYMENT & EMI has relation according to their PRICE...If I get some way to create then dynamically with the relation what they follow...then it would be great help...and fields will decrease...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements I would suggest going with the [data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module

You could create a table with all the possible combinations. Once that is done in your content type you would be displaying the required fields such as Apartment Type, Plan Type etc. When the content is chosen you can look up in the table and get the correct pricing.

There are some assumptions made here. The prices are fixed and known in advance and changes in price would be minimal. We only need to get the correct price defined byt the table.

As for the down payment and EMI I presume you would have a set rules for the same which can be calculated on the go.

Comment: I have to submit it with content submission..don't know it can be done or not.. Can you suggest me the second thing which I asked...like if FULL PAYMENT is selected then I am offering 5% discount...if I can calculate it on based of formula & token with the PRICE which I will have field...in this way..I wont need to keep table I think...because if I get some way to do it then relational fields are lot like 800 & I will get rid of them...